# Referencing InputBox value in another sub

Tags: excel, vba

In the below code, I have the user choose a cell and have that value go into a textbox within a userform as well as input "Ready for Return" into the cell 13 columns over.

Instead of having the string be inputted every time a cell is selected, I would like the string to only be inputted once a command button is pressed. Basically, I want to place the section `UserInput1.Offset(0, 13) = "Request Cancelled"` under a command button sub within a userform. Is there anyway to reference the range of an inputbox in another sub? Thanks!

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DropButtonClick()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Sample Transfer Log").Activate
Set UserInput1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select a sample transfer request # for return", Title:="Select Request #", Type:=8)
If UserInput1 = False Then
   Exit Sub
Else
    TextBox1.Text = UserInput1
    UserInput1.Offset(0, 13) = "Ready for Return"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you would need to keep the value in a global variable to access in another sub

Comment: @Sorceri Thanks a lot! I had no idea there were such a thing as global variables...I am new to VBA and programming as a whole :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Sorceri in the comments:

> you would need to keep the value in a global variable to access in another sub